# Django Rest Framework: how to set a custom name form non_field_errors?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm validating if user that is registering on my website is giving me unique address (city, street, street number etc.) and when it's not unique, then I'm raising `serializers.ValidationError`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   def validate(self, attrs):
        city = attrs['city']
        street = attrs['street']
        street_number = attrs['street_number']
        apartment_number = attrs['apartment_number'] if 'apartment_number' in attrs else None
        unique = check_address_unique(city, street, street_number, apartment_number)
        if not unique:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Another user has already been registered under this address.'))
        return attrs
```

The problem is that the field name under which the error is passed is this standard `non_field_errors`:

`{"non_field_errors":["Another user has already been registered under this address."]}`

I'd like to somehow give this error a custom name, so the desired output would be:

`{"address":["Another user has already been registered under this address."]}`

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Don't think that's the right way to do it. You're validating in the "global" validation function so the errors you raise are meant to be non-specific-field errrors. Although I haven't done the exact same thing, I think one way would be to directly append an error to a dictionary/list of errors somewhere like `self.errors` or similar (sorry, can't give you a more specific anser).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For single ValidationError you can do it like this:

```
raise serializers.ValidationError({
    'address': _('Another user has already been registered under this address.')
})
```

If you want to override this name globally, you can use the `NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY` REST framework setting.

Comment: I'll try this when I get back home. But before I do it - did you test this code, if it really behaves as desired?

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch yes, I use this very often in serializers.

Comment: I believe you and therefore I accept this answer ;)

Comment: What is this syntax? `_(`

Comment: @arshbot `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

Answer (score 3):

To avoid getting serializer validation results under the "non_field_errors" key, you can mention the desired key name in Django's REST_FRAMEWORK dict which is present in the settings file.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY": <desired key name>
}
```

this overrides the default "non_field_errors" key with the name you provide.

Answer (score 1):

Helpful might be [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/forms/validation/)

Here you find all you need to customize your ValidationError output.

For example:

```
raise ValidationError(
   _('Invalid value: %(value)s'),
   code='invalid',
   params={'value': '42'},
)
```

Comment: It's actually django rest framework I'm using, so I don't know if this will apply for my situation, but I'll definitely take a look when I get back home.